# Black screen when I move from X session to tty session

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, tty, ati, fglrx

I've the `ATI` proprietary drivers. When I power on the computer and I do the login all works well, but when I run `xorg`  I can't change `tty` or exit from `xorg` because if I try I see only a black screen (the monitor backlight stays on).

- If I change `tty` (`ctrl alt f2`) I've the black screen, if then I
  return to `xorg` (`ctrl alt f1`) it works.
- If I close or kill `xorg` I've the black screen and I must reset the
  computer.

This is the Xorg log when I go to tty2 and during the blackscreen

`[   312.470] (**) Option "fd" "24"
[   312.470] (**) Option "fd" "17"
[   312.470] (**) Option "fd" "23"
[   312.470] (**) Option "fd" "33"
[   312.470] (**) Option "fd" "20"
[   312.471] (**) Option "fd" "22"
[   312.471] (**) Option "fd" "21"
[   312.471] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[   312.471] (II) fglrx(0): Backup framebuffer data.
[   312.560] (II) fglrx(0): Backup complete.
[   312.596] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
[   312.596] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
[   312.596] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
[   312.596] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
[   312.596] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
[   312.596] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
[   312.596] (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70`

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved. I looked the log: `backup framebuffer data`, that it means that it changes framebuffer. I've thinked: "The framebuffer doesn't work maybe?". So I have try to change framebuffer using this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uvesafb and now it works.
And I think this is also the only way, for ATI proprietary drivers, to really change TTY resolution.

Answer (score 1):

ATI drivers are terrible on Linux. Try other driver versions, x and kernel too. Eventually it will work, but don't expect radeon to be stable at all. Everybody I know get continous X crashes or some artefacts, and performance is not better too.

Comment: With open drivers it worked, but I need the proprietary because are more stable and performance